# Selenium Exception "Unable to find element on closed window" using IE 11

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I run my simple selenium test case, I got "Unable to find element on closed window"

```
IWebDriver driver = new   InternetExplorerDriver(@"C:\Development\Drivers\IEDriverServer_x64_2.42.0");
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");

var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Name("q")));

IWebElement query = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
query.SendKeys("Selenium");
query.Submit();

wait.Until((d) => { return d.Title.ToLower().StartsWith("Selenium");});
driver.Quit();
```

What happes when I running my code?
When I run my code, the first thing that happen is a console is opening that tells me 
"Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit) 2.42.0.0"

The second that happens is that IE 11 start with the text
"This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server."

The third that is happen is the www.google.com is loaded and is displayed in the same web browser.

Now the test case is waiting to finding element q, but it can’t find the q element. So the test case is timed out.

But why the selenium not find the element, the webpage can is loaded and I can see the search field.
I have been working of this issue for long time now and starting getting little bit grumpy
What do I do wrong, what am I missing? 
I using VS 2013

Comment: Only use the 32bit version of the driver and check out the documentation: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#Required_Configuration...there's an extra setting to be done for the driver to have *any chance whatsoever* in communicating with IE11. Also, don't use Google. Anything, but Google.

Comment: Thanks Arran, sometimes I get blind.